# The error says "String is not a valid Boolean" in the code "CheckBoxActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString())"

Tags: vb.net

```
If (TextBoxStudentID.Text.ToString().Trim() <> "") Then
    Dim adp1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select StudentName, StudentStandard, StudentBalance, EmailAddress, ContactNumber Active from StudentDetails where StudentID = '" + TextBoxStudentID.Text.ToString() + "'", con)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adp1.Fill(ds1)
    If ds1.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        If ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            TextBoxStudentName.Text = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString()
            TextBoxStudentStd.Text = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1).ToString()
            TextBoxCurrentBalance.Text = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString()
            CheckBoxActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString())
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No student found for Student ID = " + TextBoxStudentID.Text.ToString(), "Search failed!")
            TextBoxStudentName.Text = ""
            TextBoxStudentStd.Text = ""
            TextBoxCurrentBalance.Text = ""
            TextBoxContactNumber.Text = ""
            CheckBoxActive.Checked = False
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I wrote the above code to search for a particular roll number in the database I called. The error says "the string is not a valid boolean". kindly help.

Comment: And what is the string value of ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString() ?

Comment: The number which will be inputed by the user in  the text box

Comment: So you are trying to covert a number to boolean, and which number is it?

Comment: Please, please, please use parameters. If this is a real application then do this immediately. If you are a student tell your teacher to teach parameters first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(5).ToString())
```

Column 3 is the email address. Also add a comma between `ContactNumber` and `Active`